"Not all code return a value" when loop returns
I'm a coding beginner and have a question on how to return to an array in C#. When I wrote the code, it popped out an error msg "not all code return a value".
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/J3/Distance/{city1}/{city2}/{city3}/{city4}")]
public int Route(int city1, int city2, int city3, int city4)
{
    int[] city = { city1, city2, city3, city4 };
    int[,] route = { };
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
                route[i, j] = 0;
            else if (Math.Abs(i - j) == 1)
            {
                route[i, j] = city[i];
                route[j, i] = city[i];
            }
            else if (Math.Abs(i - j) == 2)
            {
                route[i, j] = city[i] + city[i + 1];
                route[j, i] = city[i] + city[i + 1];
            }
            else if (Math.Abs(i - j) == 3)
            {
                route[i, j] = city[i] + city[i + 1] + city[i + 2];
                route[j, i] = city[i] + city[i + 1] + city[i + 2];
            }
            else
                route[i, j] = city[i] + city[i + 1] + city[i + 2] + city[i + 3];

            route[j, i] = city[i] + city[i + 1] + city[i + 2] + city[i + 3];

            return route[i, j];
        }
    }
}


The compiler doesn't realise that the loops will always return a value.

Got it, I'm looking at that answer. So how can I update the code to solve the problem. Cannot use loop? I don't really get the solution.

Do you really want to return in the first iteration (i=0 and j=0)? Probably not. Also: You initialize your route array empty. This will give an exception as soon as you access an element (because there is no element). Probably you want route = new int[6,6].

The solution is to return a default value after the outer loop, so that the method is guaranteed to always return something.

When I try to compile your code I get an "unreachable code detected" warning. Because the return is outside of the if statements it will return as soon as i == 0 and j == 0 runs just once. Also, you don't have { and } around your else statements as you do with the else if's.

You don't tell us where the error is (which you really need to for us to help you). But, I'm guessing it's this line: for (j = 0; j < 5; j++). Note that a for statement has three sub-statements. The initialization runs once before the body of the loop runs the first time. The check runs everything the loop runs before the body is executed. But the last part (j++) runs after the body runs. Since you return before the body complete, you should get an unreachable code detected warning.

Thanks everyone, I actually want to return a 5*5 array like Sample Input
3 10 12 5
Output for Sample Input
0 3 13 25 30
3 0 10 22 27
13 10 0 12 17
25 22 12 0 5
30 27 17 5 0
Explanation of Output for Sample Input
The first line of output contains:
0, since the distance from city 1 to city 1 is 0;
3, since the distance between city 1 and city 2 is 3;
13, since the distance between city 1 and city 3 is 3 + 10 = 13;
25, since the distance between city 1 and city 4 is 3 + 10 + 12 = 25;
30, since the distance between city 1 and city 5 is 3 + 10 + 12 + 5 = 30.
Version franc

@FloraJiang - Did you read my comment?

@Enigmativity, yes, that's really useful. I'm always stuck in the formatting. Sorry for the late reply, I just did not know how to reply to a specific person. Thanks, I got it and need to use "@". I'm pretty new here. So always have a lot of basic questions. Also we do not use terminal according to our professor, so my solution of using array[] for the layout actually does not work.

@FloraJiang - What do you mean by "using array[] for the layout"?

@Enigmativity I want to return a 5*5 array instead of a specific number.
